# Calling Stored Procedure With List Parameter

Tags: java, sql-server, arraylist, mybatis

I am unable to figure out how to send a list as a parameter to SQL Server Stored Procedure using myBatis

```
     call sp(List<Object>)
```

I have a stored procedure inside a SQL Server(2012) which takes a parameter of type list.

```
 CREATE TypeTable of Table 
 (
   @FKId IN
@FKId INT
@FKId INT
@FKId INT
@FKId INT
@userName VARCHAR
)
```

My Stored Procedure call

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE SP(@TypeTableList Typetable READONLY ) 

  AS
  BEGIN 
  /*  My DB Operations To Enter New Records and Thier Child Records */
  END
```

MyMapper

```
<select id="mapperId" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
     call sp(#{list})
</select>
```

POJO

```
public class ListClass {

private Long fk1;
private Long fk2;
private Long fk3;
private Long fk4;
private Long fk5;
private String userName;

public ListClass() {
    super();
}

public Long getFk1() {
    return fk1;
}

public void setFk1(Long fk1) {
    this.fk1 = fk1;
}

public Long getFk2() {
    return fk2;
}

public void setFk2(Long fk2) {
    this.fk2 = fk2;
}

public Long getFk3() {
    return fk3;
}

public void setFk3(Long fk3) {
    this.fk3 = fk3;
}

public Long getFk4() {
    return fk4;
}

public void setFk4(Long fk4) {
    this.fk4 = fk4;
}

public Long getFk5() {
    return fk5;
}

public void setFk5(Long fk5) {
    this.fk5 = fk5;
}

public String getuserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setuserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
 }
```

I have tried using type handler of type array but i always get a exception.

I have not found any resources on creating a custom type handler for ArrayList With SQL Server

Any Help would be appriciated

Thankyou

Comment: Per the docs the parameter value must be "SQLServerDataTable, from a ResultSet or from a user provided implementation of the ISQLServerDataRecord"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create` statement you posted didn't work in SQL Server 2017, so I'll show you a simpler example.

DDLs:

```sql
create table Users (
  id int,
  name varchar(20)
);

create type UserTableType as table (
  id int,
  name varchar(20)
);

create procedure uspAddUsers
  @UserTable UserTableType READONLY
as
begin
    insert into Users (id, name)
      select * from @UserTable
end;
```

POJO:

```java
public class User {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  // getter/setter
}
```

Mapper method:

```java
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@Insert("{call uspAddUsers(#{users,typeHandler=pkg.UserListTypeHandler})}")
void insertUsers(@Param("users") List<User> users);
```

Note the `typeHandler` option.
As David Browne pointed out, the driver requires `SQLServerDataType` as the input, so you may need a type handler that converts the list into a `SQLServerDataType`.
The below is a simple type handler implementation.

```java
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataTable;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement;

public class UserListTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<List<User>>{
  @Override
  public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps,
      int i, List<User> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
      throws SQLException {
    SQLServerDataTable dataTable = new SQLServerDataTable();
    dataTable.addColumnMetadata("id", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    dataTable.addColumnMetadata("name", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    for (User user : parameter) {
      dataTable.addRow(user.getId(), user.getName());
    }
    ps.unwrap(SQLServerPreparedStatement.class)
      .setStructured(i, "UserTableType", dataTable);
  }
  // getNullableResult() won't be used
}
```

An executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56633915) tested with...

- Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU15) (KB4498951) - 14.0.3162.1 (X64)
- mssql-jdbc 7.3.1.jre8-preview