# How can I select with list of entities in mybatis?

Tags: sql-server, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis with MSSQL's stored procedure.

When I want to select with single entity, I can use it like this:

```
@Select("{call PROC_SELECT_FOO(#{id}, #{condition})}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
FooEntity selectFoo( FooEntity fooEntity );
```

But when I want to select a list of entities with multiple `ids` and `conditions`, the following code doesn't work as I expected:

```
@Select("{call PROC_SELECT_FOO_LIST(#{id}, #{condition})}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
List<FooEntity> selectFooList( List<FooEntity> fooEntity );
```

Is it considered best practice to execute `selectFoo(FooEntity)` multiple times?

Or, should I create a new class that has `List<Long> ids` and `String condition` using `id IN(SPLIT_STRING(@ids, ','))`?

Comment: This [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56633915) contains the information you are looking for, I think (it was for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56633915/1261766), btw). If not, please provide a small demo project like mine or add more information so that we can reproduce the same issue on our end.